# App is rejected "Reasons Program License Agreement PLA 3.3.12"

Tags: ios, identifier, ads

My App is rejected by App store. There is iAd and GoogleAnalytics(version 3.10) in the App.While submitting App to store I selected first 2 and Limit Ad Tracking settings in below screenshot.[image]

See image of framework that I have added 
[image]

It shows following reason :

Reasons

Program License Agreement
PLA 3.3.12

We found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement states:

"You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the reset Advertising Identifier."

Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager, or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd support.

If your app is serving ads, please:

- Ensure that you have tested your app on a device, not just the simulator, and that you have removed all previous versions of your app prior to testing
- Provide us the steps to locate ads in your app

If your app does not serve ads, please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:

class: ASIdentifierManager
selector: advertisingIdentifier
framework: AdSupport.framework

If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have included ad functionality.

To help locate the Advertising Identifier, use the “nm” tool. For information on the “nm” tool, please see the nm man page.

If you do not have access to the libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool lists the methods that the library calls, and "otool -ov" will list the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides.

**Any idea what may be the result?**

Comment: It looks like [this](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=387) is relevant.

Comment: what is that libAdIdAccess.a file?

Comment: libAdid is file of google analytic.

Comment: Use the latest version of google analytics sdk and remove the following files from your app

libAdIdAccess.a
AdSupport.framework.
Download the latest SDK here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the advertising identifier for neither iAd nor GA.

**iAd**

Citation from Apple's response (in your question):

> Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager, or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd support.

**GA**

The GA iOS SDK allows you to *optionally* use the advertising identifier (which obviously enhances the tracking/analytics possibilities). Its use is optional exactly because of this Apple policy (only use the ad id for advertising purposes). So, if you can't justify the use of the advertising identifier to Apple, you probably have to opt-out of GA ad id tracking (which you do by not linking against `libAdIdAccess.a` and the `AdSupport.framework`).